# AmChart export change font color on export

Tags: svg, export, amcharts

i have i problem and tried different solutions, but no success. 
I have an amChartXY chart, which has white labels and legend text is white, but when i want to build custom pdf report, i cannot convert those white text into black.
First i have a function which exports chart to base64 string, and i want there to convert the text color to black, but it won't work.
Here is a code snippet of a menu item, that converts to SVG that is saved to global array object.

```
menu: [
            {
                class: "",
                label: "Save to draft",
                click: function() {
                    var overrideObject = {
                        backgroundColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                        color : "#000",
                        legend : {
                            color : "#000"
                        }
                    };
                    var chartObject = this;
                        chartObject.capture(overrideObject, function () {
                            chartObject.toJPG({}, function (base64) {
                            // charts is global array 
                                    charts.push({
                                        name: customName,
                                        chart: base64
                                    });
                            });
                        });
                }
            },
```

Here the `overrideObject` is changing the backgroundColor attribute with white ( before is was transparent ) but it's not changing font color. Also i have tried different attributes to add, but nothing seems to work. 
Is this possible at capture time ?

Here are some images preview of what i want to accomplish :
[image: Image with transparent background]
[image: Image with white background]
AmChart for export isn't that well documented, so any feedback would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overrideObject you're passing only accepts the same parameters listed [in the list of export settings](https://github.com/amcharts/export#complete-list-of-available-export-settings). If you need to change the appearance of specific elements on the chart, you need to use the `reviver` callback mentioned in [the annotation settings section](https://github.com/amcharts/export#annotation-settings) to selectively apply your modifications. For example, here's how to target the value axis labels:

```
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "reviver": function(nodeObj) {
      if (nodeObj.className === 'amcharts-axis-label' && nodeObj.svg.parentNode.classList.contains('amcharts-value-axis')) {
        nodeObj.fill = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
```

Note that you need to use SVG attributes to change the appearance, so you'll have to set the fill to change the color of the text element.

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e33909dae2e64eeadff29333869986fc?editors=0010)

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ( such a small part in documentation for this, i didn't even saw it when i was reading it )